# Problem after implement packagingExcludes in maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, spring-boot-maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

I have app that build with different profiles using spring profiles. i have to implement packagingExcludes to exclude websocket-*.jar because its make conflict with tomcat after deploy.
so , i add some code to implement packagingExcludes , refer to this site [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html)

```
<configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
```

- maven version : apache-maven-3.6.3
- maven-war-plugin : 3.3.1
- spring-boot-maven-plugin : 2.5.3

After run `mvn package -P test` in terminal , i have lot of files in target folder

[folder target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjkzJ.png)

including war file and original file.

After check these file, i realized 2 things :

- In war file, websocket jar still there and not deleted yet
- In original file, websocket jar can't found/deleted , which mean packagingExcludes success. But the problem org folder also cannot found in these file, and cause this file can't run in local or web server.
  [original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uKGF.png)

My goal is : Make war file / not original file without websocket jar inside.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>sc-stream-mep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>stream-mep</name>
    <description>Services stream data to mep mrp</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jfairy.version>0.5.9</jfairy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
            <version>${jfairy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/timestamp-interceptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>timestamp-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        fixing CVE-2021-45105 issue , happen in log4j 2.14 version  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stream-mep</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*websocket*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/dev.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/test.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/uat.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/production.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Remove war plugin, remove version from tomcat dependency, set scope to provided. Redeploy. The jackson dependency isn't needed either. Remove the log4j2 dependencies, include `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` and add `<log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>` to your `<properties>` section. You are trying to be smarter then what it already provided, leading to these issues.

Comment: Also Upgrade Maven version to the most recent version.

Comment: And forgot, ditch the `maven-war-plugin`.

Comment: is any possible maven version cause of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to be smarter then what is already provided by Spring Boot.

1. Remove the `maven-war-plugin`.
2. Set `scope` to `provided` for the tomcat dependency
3. Remove `version` from the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (you are mixing versions, 2.2.4 and 2.5.3, don't mix versions
4. The jackson dependency is already part of `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Which would make your `pom.xml` look something like the following

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>sc-stream-mep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>stream-mep</name>
    <description>Services stream data to mep mrp</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jfairy.version>0.5.9</jfairy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
            <version>${jfairy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/timestamp-interceptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>timestamp-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        fixing CVE-2021-45105 issue , happen in log4j 2.14 version  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stream-mep</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>                    
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/dev.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/test.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>                   
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/uat.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>                   
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/production.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

You can even make it better by removing the `log4j2` dependencies and instead use the `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` and include a version to use in your `<properties/>` section.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>sc-stream-mep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>stream-mep</name>
    <description>Services stream data to mep mrp</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jfairy.version>0.5.9</jfairy.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
            <version>${jfairy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/timestamp-interceptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>timestamp-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stream-mep</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>                    
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/dev.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/test.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>                   
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/uat.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>                   
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <delete
                                                file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/production.properties"
                                              tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Finally you are also building artifacts per environment, which basically means you will run untested artifacts in production. Spring can perfectly load the correct configuration if you specify which profile is active. Then by renamed your environment specific properties file to `application-<environment>.properties` Spring Boot will automatically load it and you could ditch the copying around of files (and produce a single artifact which you can promote throuh your environment.

`dev.properties` -> `application-dev.properties`
`test.properties` -> `application-test.properties`
`uat.properties` -> `application-uat.properties`
`production.properties` -> `application.properties`.

Now when running the application on the environment make sure that a SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE property is set in the environment or as Tomcat context variable. (For production it isn't needed).

When doing so you end up with a really clean and easy `pom.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>sc-stream-mep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>stream-mep</name>
    <description>Services stream data to mep mrp</description>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jfairy.version>0.5.9</jfairy.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
            <version>${jfairy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/timestamp-interceptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>timestamp-interceptor</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stream-mep</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice,
i can't remove maven-war-plugin cause this plugin help me to remove websocket-*.jar that make conflict in tomcat.
Like i said , 
My goal is : Make war file / not original file without websocket jar inside , and i suggest that jar still there

Comment: Yesyou can as that problem is introduced due to the wrong scope of your tomcat dependency. Please read instead of jumping to conclusions.

Comment: just try pom.xml that you give, its not solve my problem.
websocket jar still in war file and .original file

Comment: It will be there but in a lib-provided directory. If not you are doing something that you aren't showing us. But as stated before judging from all that in yuor `pom.xml` you are solving problems you actually introduced yourself by how you build your application.

Comment: And there is something pulling in a full jetty including websocket support. So you acatually have a server in a server which is the main culprit. The `io.confluent:timestamp-interceptor` dependency pulls in half the internet including a full jetty with websockets. Not sure why it does that or that you actually need that full library or justpart. But that is your main issue, so figure out ifyou really need it or just a single part of that (which you should include).